# Jboss patch to eap 7.0.,5 | java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/ssl/internal/ssl/Provider

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-7

i am getting below error while doing log in to my application which uses Java 8 and Jboss 7.0.5 (just patched from 7.0.4 to 7.0.5) :
 11:57:19,190 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/ssl/internal/ssl/Provider 2018-01-02 11:57:19,190 [default task-7] ERROR stderr - Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/ssl/internal/ssl/Provider

This error has been occuring after applying patch 
any help valuable suggestions would be really appriciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Jboss 7 looks for dependencies in the modules folder. You can't just go in the modules.xml file and add new modules if they don't actually exist.

What you need to do is find out whether there is a jar containing the missing class, if it exist then you need to add a reference to that module from your project, if does not exist, you need to manually download it and copy it to the modules directory and then reference it.

You have several ways you can reference it:

Add a classpath entry to your manifest file: Classpath: com.sun.net
Add a global reference to that module in your standalone.xml by adding a  [Global module](https://developer.jboss.org/message/731450).
For more details, [look here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Home).